# Local maximum is global maximum

Tags: calculus

Let f(x,y)=Ax²+By²+Cxy+Dx+Ey+L, with A,B,C,D,E and L real numbers. Show that if (x₀,y₀) is a local maximum (or local minimum) of f, then it is a global maximum

Answer (score 0):

**HINTS:**

1)the global extrema occur at location(s) where the partial derivatives of $f$ with respect to both $x$ and $y$ vanish.

2. Take the partial derivatives, set them to zero and create a linear system in $x$ and $y$
3. How many solutions does this system have?

For extra credit, how do you determine if this extremum is a maximum or a minimum?